# Select subset of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I know this is a very basic question but I'm new to XML and while it seems simple, I can't find a simple answer anywhere.  I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root version="1">
<targets>
    <target type="email">
        <property name="to">b1q23@email.com</property>
    </target>
    <target type="fob"/>
</targets>
<observation uniqueID="00A60D" deviceID="308610ea23">
    <field name="field1">test1</field>
    <field name="field2">test2</field>
</observation>
```

and I'm trying to either select a subset of that xml, or remove nodes, to get it pared down to:

```
    <observation uniqueID="00A60D" deviceID="308610ea23">
    <field name="attachments">
        <string>1910.jpg</string>
    </field>
    <field name="field1">test1</field>
    <field name="field2">test2</field>
</observation>
```

So that I can deserialize it into an object.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You "subset" does not appear to be a subset `<field name="attachments">
        <string>1910.jpg</string>
    </field>` does not apear in the original XML. Also in your riginal XML the `<root>` element is not closed so it is not correctly formatted, I assume this is a copy paste error.

Comment: Seems you should work more to clarify your question. Where does 1910.jpg comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<root version=\"1\">" +
        "<targets>" +
            "<target type=\"email\">" +
                "<property name=\"to\">b1q23@email.com</property>" +
            "</target>" +
            "<target type=\"fob\"/>" +
        "</targets>" +
        "<observation uniqueID=\"00A60D\" deviceID=\"308610ea23\">" +
            "<field name=\"field1\">test1</field>" +
            "<field name=\"field2\">test2</field>" +
        "</observation>" +
        "</root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
var observationNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/root/observation");

var observationXml = observationNode.OuterXml;
```

Comment: I was close but didn't realize I needed to use .OuterXml, that was the catch.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a XML to LINQ Version:

```
dynamic root= XElement.Load(dataStream).Descendants("root")
                        .Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

This will give all the `root` element from the document.And you can access root

Comment: Why `dynamic`? Isn't it just `XElement[]`? Or `var` for type inference?

Comment: after that you can access element by its name

Comment: I like this solution but I'm even newer to Lambda expressions so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, for me anyway, for the time being.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse("<root version ..." // etc. to parse a string. 
// Use XElement.Load to load a file.

var observations = root.Elements("observation");
```

It assumes one root (by definition) and possibly multiple `observation` elements.